# How can i get blog_post.title with latest comment building a custom sql query?

Tags: python, sql, database, django

The sql query:

```
select id,title 
from blog_post inner join (select object_pk, max(submit_date) 
                           from django_comments 
                           group by object_pk 
                           order by submit_date DESC) as foo 
where foo.object_pk=blog_post.id;
```

How can i get the same result using django `model.objects.get` function? How can i write custom query with django for this? Is there anything like

```
model.objects.getwithsqlquery('''select id,title 
from blog_post inner join (select object_pk, max(submit_date) 
                           from django_comments 
                           group by object_pk 
                           order by submit_date DESC) as foo 
where foo.object_pk=blog_post.id;''')
```

mysql tables are:

```
mysql> describe blog_post;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id  | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content  | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe django_comments;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content_type_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| object_pk       | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| site_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_name       | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_email      | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_url        | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment         | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| submit_date     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address      | char(15)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_public       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_removed      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: [Performing raw SQL queries in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)